# How do I get to nassau without any glitches occurring?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

So I have been playing assassins creed black flag. But I have never been able really reach Nassau. I would end up crashing the game or get stuck in a infinite loading screen. I play this on Xbox one if that helps any? What causes this glitch? How do I fix or avoid this? Is there a certain path I must take?

Comment: https://youtu.be/QkKCMI1Lyyw Try this video. It is a possible solution.

Comment: No that's just a video of being stuck in a infinite loading screen.

Comment: Do you have any more information about when the crash occurs? eg is it happening every time you pass a certain location, when its trying to load a cut-scene, etc

Comment: It happens every time I try to travel to Nassau. I will approach Nassau and it will prompt me to go to Nassau. If I try to decline my ship is turned around. If I accept. The game will crash or get stuck in a infinite loading screen with Edward Kenway.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you because it helped me

1. Uninstall the game
2. Go to the store and search for black flag
3. Instead of purchase it should say install
4. Install the game, make sure it says it's installing from the network

You won't lose any progress

Answer (score 0):

Only works if you don't only own the disc idk what console y'all have but my Xbox one does not let me install without the disc or from specifically the store without purchase or the game being in the console which will not fix this bug